# How to debug worker?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have code with Worker in JavaScript

```
var worker = new Worker("indexWorker.js");

worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  oDefer.resolve();                                                                                
}, false);

worker.postMessage({
  "data": allData                                                                        
});

return oDefer.promise;
```

How I can debug the `indexWorker.js`?
I looked on the web and I saw that I need to do this in the Chrome the developer tool, however the option of the worker doesn't exist on Chrome that I can find.

Could you please advise me ?

Comment: `var worker = new Worker(indexWorker.js); ` is missing quotes around the file name. Also, add a `debugger` statement in your code. If you have dev tools open, it will stop at that point.

Comment: do I need to add debugger in the indexWorker.js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to add

```
debugger;
```

To a line in your code. If dev tool is open, it will stop the code and open the debugger. See http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/YUKSu/82/

You can add `debugger` to the file that is running as a webworker (`indexWorker.js`) or to the code responding to its messages.